# I am performing a validation check before photo is uploaded, so using promises, but before validation check is completed, image will be set in a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code to perform validation check before image is uploaded and stored in a state, the above two function is the validation check function for image and returns true or fase based on the condition and this is asyncronus function which return promises. and i am calling this function below, if both passes the test then only it should move forward and stored in state otherwise it should not, but the problem i am facing is before it performs validation check and returns promises, image is already stored in state. how to resolve this issue.

```js
const faceBookImageValidation =async (files) => {
        if (files.length === 0) {
            console.log("no file")
            return true;
        }

    const extension = ['jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif', 'tiff'];
    const fileType = files[0]?.file?.name?.split('.')[1]
    const fSizeMB = Math.round((files[0]?.file?.size / 1048576));

    console.log("fileType", fileType)
    console.log("files", files)
    console.log("fileSize", fSizeMB)

    if (files?.length > 0 && !extension.includes(fileType)) {
        toast.error('Please upload a valid image (jpeg, png, bmp, gif, tiff)', {
            duration: 5000,
            position: 'top-center',
            style: {
                borderRadius: '10px',
                background: '#333',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            id:"validationCheck"
        });
        return false;
    }
    else if (files?.length > 0 && fSizeMB >= 4) {
        toast.error('File size should be less than 4MB', {
            duration: 5000,
            position: 'top-center',
            style: {
                borderRadius: '10px',
                background: '#333',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            id:"validationCheck"
        });
        return false;
    }
    else if (files?.length > 0 && fileType === 'png' && fSizeMB >= 1) {
        toast.error('File size should be less than 1MB', {
            duration: 5000,
            position: 'top-center',
            style: {
                borderRadius: '10px',
                background: '#333',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            id:"validationCheck"
        });
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}

const instagramImageValidation =async (files) => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
        console.log("no file")
        return true;
    }

    const extension = ['jpeg'];
    const fileType = files[0]?.file?.name?.split('.')[1]
    const fSizeMB = Math.round((files[0]?.file?.size / 1048576));
    const { width, height } = await reactImageSize(files[0]?.data_url);
    
    console.log("fileType", fileType)
    console.log("files", files)
    console.log("fileSize", fSizeMB)
    console.log("width",width , "height", height)
    console.log("aspect ratio" , height/width)

    if (files?.length > 0 && !extension.includes(fileType)) {
        toast.error('Please upload a valid image (jpeg)', {
            duration: 5000,
            position: 'top-center',
            style: {
                borderRadius: '10px',
                background: '#333',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            id:"validationCheck"
        });
        return false;
    }
    else if (files?.length > 0 && fSizeMB >= 8) {
        toast.error('File size should be less than 8MB', {
            duration: 5000,
            position: 'top-center',
            style: {
                borderRadius: '10px',
                background: '#333',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            id:"validationCheck"
        });
        return false;
    }
    else if (files?.length > 0 && width < 320 && width > 1440) {
        toast.error('Image width should be between 320 to 1440 px', {
            duration: 5000,
            position: 'top-center',
            style: {
                borderRadius: '10px',
                background: '#333',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            id:"validationCheck"
        });
        return false;
    }
    else if (files?.length > 0 && (height/width) > .8 && (height/width) > 1.91) {
        toast.error('Aspect ratio should be between .8 to 1.91', {
            duration: 5000,
            position: 'top-center',
            style: {
                borderRadius: '10px',
                background: '#333',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            id:"validationCheck"
        });
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}

    /* IMAGE UPLOAD FUNCTION */



const onSelectedImageList =async (imageList) => {
        console.log('imageList: ', imageList);
        console.log("profileObjects-->", profileObjects)

    const lengthTest =await Promise.all( profileObjects.filter(async (o) => {
        if (o.platformType === "facebook") {
            const res = await faceBookImageValidation(imageList)
            return res
        }
        if (o.platformType === "instagram") {
            const res =  await instagramImageValidation(imageList)
            return res
        }
      
    }))
    console.log(lengthTest, " ", profileObjects)
    if (
        lengthTest.length === profileObjects.length
    ) {
        setSelectedImages(imageList);
    } else {
        console.log("failed")
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you know that it's stored inside the state before validation? Also, you wanted to use `map`, not `filter`. Now `Promise.all` has nothing to await for. `await Promise.all( profileObjects.map(async (o) => {
        if (o.platformType === "facebook") {
            const res = await faceBookImageValidation(imageList)
            return res
        }
        if (o.platformType === "instagram") {
            const res =  await instagramImageValidation(imageList)
            return res
        }
      
    })).filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` expects a **list of promises** as an argument. Your code passes an array of data objects instead, somewhat similar to:

```js
const lengthTest = await Promise.all([100, 200, 300]);
```

I mean, this: `profileObjects.filter(...)` produces a (probably filtered) list of profile objects, not a list of promises. If you pass a list of objects to the `Promise.all`  you'll simply get the input list as an output.

You could try something closer to this maybe (at least use `map` instead of `filter`):

```js
    const validated = await Promise.all( profileObjects.map((o) => {
        if (o.platformType === "facebook") {
            return faceBookImageValidation(imageList)
        }
        if (o.platformType === "instagramm") {
            return instagramImageValidation(imageList)
        }
     })
...
    if (
        validated.every(r => r === true)
    ) {
```